# Using 2 internet connection simultaniously for different purpose

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, dropbox

I'm on windows 10x64, at work we have a proxy which requires authentification, block some stuff such as SSH or Ips (dropbox, and other stuff)

Thing is, I have my little collection of scripts (hundreds of python scripts, 10Mb) that I use here and there.

They are synchronized between all my computers using dropbox, so when I change one it is updated everywhere.

Now for work I have to bring them on a thumbdrive and sometimes I correct a bug at work, forget to update my file at home and make a modification at home, this is a nightmare.

I'd like to be able to use dropbox at work, just for my "python_scripts" folder.
I have 50GB of data available on my phone plan.

**Is it possible to connect the computer to my phone in wifi, while being connected to the corporation network in LAN and redirect everything coming in and out of dropbox toward the wifi connection?**

Thanks.

Comment: You might benefit more from switching to git version control which has not a central repository (your shared drop box folder is a central repo) but is meant to work on a local repository and has means to sync different repositories in various ways. There are many ways to access git repositories, maybe one complient with your corporation's security. You might even use email to send patches. (https://stackoverflow.com/q/85051/2579220)

Comment: I can't push to github or bitbucket from work.

Sending patches throught email is the same thing, you have to remember to do it, you have to remember to retrieve them, it's a hassle.

Switching from the 2 internet connection is also a hassle, I'd really like to have everything working without doing anything other than plugging my phone in the morning.

Comment: There's probably a reason your employer has decided to block access to code/personal stuff. You might be liable to written warnings or dismissal if you try to circumvent these kinds of restrictions.

Comment: dropbox access is blocked because it would generate too much traffic on the network. plus they don't want their stuff on an other company servers.
My employer is ok and I would even say happy with me using my personal scripts.

it's stuff like csv cleaners, end of line repair, small utility scripts.